# Delegates is not working?

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

here is my protocol definition.

```
protocol ActivityIndicatorDelegate: class {
    func showIndicator()
    func hideIndicator()
    func barcodeError()
    func categoryError()
    func descError()
    func reasonError()
    func costError()
}
```

Then in my Custom cell class I create weak reference and I call delegate function

```
class ProductTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var indicatorDelegate: ActivityIndicatorDelegate?
   @IBAction func stockUpdate(_ sender: Any) {
        indicatorDelegate?.categoryError()
   }
}
```

Then in my UITableViewController class

```
class ProductTableViewController: 

    UITableViewController,ActivityIndicatorDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let cellDelegate = ProductTableViewCell()
            cellDelegate.indicatorDelegate = self
    }
func categoryError() {
                //self.showAlert(alertTitle: "Error!", alertMessage: "Category Should not be empty")
                print("Error")
            }
        }
```

I have written all these in a single file. What I'm doing wrong here? Can some one help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set the delegate in `viewDidLoad`. This will only set the delegate of the cell that you just created, instead of all the cells in the table view.

You should do this in `celForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeue...
// configure the cell...
cell.indicatorDelegate = self
```